# Cannot change monitor frequency to maximum 75Hz

Tags: windows, graphics-card, hdmi

I have a laptop with i5 generation 11 with Iris Xe video card connected via HDMI to a Phillips monitor PHL 273V7 and in windows 10 or 11 I cannot change frequency to 75Hz

now, the monitor supports that frequency (my old laptop was working very well with that frequency, also connected with HDMI, and my work laptop works on that monitor with that frequency

also, the video card supports that frequency be cause I managed to boot Linux Mint install ISO and that frequency is present and can be set (I have image after setting it)

I also tried QRes and it say that frequency is not supported

**SO, any ideea what to do to get that frequency ?**

Thank you

LE: I did tried to install latest drivers for video card and monitor, with no luck

and I refuse to believe that is absolutely no solution

Answer (score 0):

From the
[Comparison page of all Intel Iris Xe Graphics models](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/compare.html?productIds=196656,208659,208660,196655,197384,208663,208081,208078,208076,208082,208657,208658,208922,208661,208662,208921,208664),
I find that the maximum frequency advertised is 60Hz for all models.

I don't think that there is a method to force this video card
beyond its specifications, or that it's healthy to force it
beyond them.

To try and force your resolution & frequency, you may use the
[Custom Resolution Utility (CRU)](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU).

Comment: that's the maximum resolution, and again, in Linux I can see and set 75Hz, so, it must be a solution in windows too

Comment: Have you tried the [Intel Driver & Support Assistant](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html) to install the best driver for the Iris Xe video card?

Comment: yes, I installed latest driver, let me put this in question

Comment: Try to force your resolution & frequency using the [Custom Resolution Utility (CRU)](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU).

Comment: please put this as answer and not as comment, so, I can flag it as the right answer, it did the trick ... THANK YOU !

Comment: Done as requested.